# Fetch api return same data always

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

Every time one of my button is clicked, I trigger a call to the [adviceslip](https://api.adviceslip.com/advice)  API to get an `advice` data. I expect the payload to vary. But the exact same data is returned after each call.

I've tried to call `getAdvice` function as a callback but it didn't work.

Am I missing something?

```js
'use strict'

const title = document.querySelector('.advice-title')
const desc = document.querySelector('.advice-text')
const btn = document.querySelector('.btn')



const getAdvice = async () =>{
    try{
        const response = await fetch('https://api.adviceslip.com/advice');
        if (!response.ok){
            throw new Error('Api connection problem')
        }
        const responseJson = await response.json();
        const data = responseJson.slip;

        const id = `ADVICE #${data.id}`;
        const advice = `"${data.advice}"`;

        title.textContent = id;
        desc.textContent = advice;

    }
    catch (e) {
        console.error(e)
    }

}



btn.addEventListener('click', () => {
    getAdvice()
})
```

Comment: It seems to mostly work here: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/xbjdp5qz/.  The source of the data does not appear to return different data if you make two closely spaced requests.  But, with a small delay between requests I get a different response each time.

Comment: The occasional duplicates look like it may be a caching problem.  If I change the URL to `'https://api.adviceslip.com/advice?t=' + Math.random()`, I get a unique response every time.

Comment: OK, updated the jsFiddle here with the t=xxx fix: https://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/a6yzvqsj/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There appears to be an issue with caching where multiple requests closely spaced in time from a web page will cause the same result to come back.  If I add a uniquely changing value to the URL to defeat caching like this:

```
const response = await fetch('https://api.adviceslip.com/advice?t=' + Math.random());
```

Then, I get a unique response every time.

I experimented with sending various headers to disable caching instead of the `t=xxx` hack, but those headers trigger a CORs error and the `fetch()` does not succeed because custom headers like this don't pass the test for a "simple" CORS request and thus require pre-flight which the target site does not support.  So, the `?t=xxx` where `xxx` is different on each request seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

I found this and it worked for me. Add
`const response = await fetch("https://api.adviceslip.com/advice",  { cache: "no-cache" });`